# joining 3 variabel to 1 as string in python

Tags: python

i have 3 variabel below, it is dosen, matkul, and pertemuan

```
def base()
    day = localtime.tm_wday
    time = localtime.tm_hour
    no = str(nomor)
    dosen = cek_dosen(no)
    if dosen == 'null':
        no_dosen()
    elif dosen != 'null':
        ada_dosen()
        matkul = cek_jadwal(day,time)
        if matkul == 'null':
            no_jadwal()
        elif matkul != 'null':
            ada_matkul()
            pertemuan = cek_pertemuan(matkul)
            print pertemuan
            if pertemuan > 1:
                cek_before(pertemuan)
                filename = dosen,matkul,pertemuan
                print filename
            else:
                filename = dosen,matkul,pertemuan
                print filename
```

i want to make the filename is string that come from these variabel, if `dosen = DOSEN1`, `matkul = MATKUL1`, and `pertemuan = 1`, so that `filename = DOSEN1MATKUL11`. i have try `filename = dosen, matkul, pertemuan` , but the output is `('DOSEN2', 'MATKUL2', '1L')` . Sorry for my bad english

Comment: It could be done with filename = dosen + matkul + str(pertemuan). If dosen or matkul could possibly be integers instead of strings then wrap each in str() too - it is ok to wrap a string with str() if in doubt, no harm done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join strings by using the [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) method.

Your first two items are already strings, your third one isn't. So you have to convert it first to a string.

```
filename = ''.join([dosen, matkul, str(pertemuan)])
```

Comment: ive tries, but it has following error
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected string, long found

Answer (score 0):

.join or. Format use any of the string function will work very well. But your object can have method too todo this